# How do I restore the request/response details in Edge Devtools?

Tags: edge-devtools

Right now my Edge DevTools no longer shows the request/response information - headers, body etc. for a highlighted request.

[image]

I have read the [Edge DevTools documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network/#inspect-the-details-of-the-resource) which says that clicking a request should show the request/response details but this doesn't work.

**How can I see header/body details for a highlighted request, ie, how can I get the UI back?**

Answer (score 2):

**Answering my own question to help others**

Highlighting the row with the request will not show the header/body details.

Only highlighting the first column in the row will show the header/body details.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, this was it. What a strange interface design.